# how can i extract rapidminer xpath value from javascript

Tags: rapidminer

I would like to extract rapidminer xpath value for longitude and latitude embedded in javascript.

```
    < script type = "text/javascript" >
      $("document").ready(function() {
        MultiMaps.init('{"elementName":"map","latitude":"55.046253842870506","longitude":"-8.275406306447621","zoom":16,"showMarker":true,"showArea":false,"areaSize":0,"showControls":1,"draggable":1,"maxZoom":18,"minZoom":7,"hitcode":"100","zoomLocked":false,"lateLoad":true,"lateLoadIds":"#smi-map-link","bizmapWaitTime":"800","multipleAreas":[],"mapButtons":["map-button"],"satButtons":["sat-button"],"svButtons":["sv-button"],"clustering":true,"isMarkerDraggable":false,"jumpToGoogleIds":"","key":"AIzaSyBvf2e2eg1SyR7Lq5INzGDrIInkgKHT1oI","onlyGoogle":true,"lazyLoad":false}');
      }); < /script>
```

I tried

```
//h:html/head/script[@type='text/javascript']//text()
```

to at least extract all the text from the javascript but it is not working for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JAVA string functions. Find the starting point of the latitude and then extract n number of characters. Do the same for longitude.